# Freeradius on Linux with dynamic VLAN assignment via AD

Tags: active-directory, freeradius2, dynamic-vlan-assignment

I've been trying to configure my freeradius server on Linux to authenticate users from an existing Active Directory (windows server 2003) and i've already done that. Now i need to assign VLANs to those users and i dont know how to :(. The logical procedure should be with an AD attribute but i haven't found which one nor how to read it from the AD to use it on the freeradius server... Can anyone help me with this or tell me where can i find a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use users file(for wi-fi change "Ethernet" to "Wireless-802.11")

```
DEFAULT NAS-Port-Type == "Ethernet", Ldap-Group == "Group1", Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 10, Tunnel-Type = VLAN    
DEFAULT NAS-Port-Type == "Ethernet", Ldap-Group == "Group2", Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = 20, Tunnel-Type = VLAN
```